# How to keep a transformation after "set parent" if "clear and keep trasformation" doesn't work?

Tags: modeling, mesh, bezier-curves, parent

I'm using Blender for architecture modeling and I'm having a problem with the clear parent command.
I made a fence repeating a mesh on a bezier curve with the "make parent" and follow the father.
Now I want to work on this fence in edit mode but I can't really do it, I can just change the initial object and it changes all the elements along the perimeter. 
I tried the command "clear and keep transformation" but it doesn't work as I expected.

There is a way to turn my fence a mesh more editable?

I took 2 screenshots

before clear parent and keep transformation
[image: clear parent and keep transformation]

after clear and keep transformation the elements are gone.
[image: after clear and keep transformation]

Comment: Can you try bringing the parent's location back to 0,0,0 before clearing the child and comment back on if the results were any different please?

Comment: Do you mean [this location](http://imageshack.com/a/img921/7774/M07jPH.jpg) ?


No difference :/

Comment: Is any modifier involved in the creation of your object, that has not been applied? It's would be best if you can post a .blend file so we could take a look at the setting which may have created this behavior.

Comment: I didn't use modifier :/ this is the model !!

[blender model](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=9146BA2382953394!1154&authkey=!AIMZ4cUMmhDuznc&ithint=file%2cblend)

Comment: I looked at the file, but I'm very curious as to one thing, how did you create the array? Regardless of that, I think that before you parent these to together, you need to apply at least scale, but scale and rotation would be wise for BOTH of the objects. I found this out by looking at the scale factor of both objects. They are both not 1.0, this is definitely causing problems, because if I highlight the Circle and apply the scale, your array gets scaled way out away from the center, and this is all before clearing the parent.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>   and choose *Clear and Keep Transformation*.